# OSM foot traffic data?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, openstreetmap, traffic

Does [OpenStreetMap](https://openstreetmap.org) ([Nominatim](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/)?) have foot traffic data? Or are there any open-access databases that show foot traffic data (analogously to [TrafficView](https://trafficview.org/live_traffic/) for traffic)?

Comment: If you're talking about traffic in the sense of "how many people go through there?", OSM does not provide any such data (be it by foot or other means of transportation). If your scope is worldwide, it seems difficult to find free resources for that (not to mention *reliable* resources). On the other hand, if you're just looking for data about specific places, you might find free databases, if local authorities deemed it worthwhile to gather and provide data about that. For example for the 19 boroughs of Montreal: https://ouvert.canada.ca/data/dataset/584de76b-13b9-47ea-af12-0c37b8eb5de5

Comment: @J-J-J [Google Maps provides data on the amount of visitors each hour for a particular location.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60652129/1429450)

Comment: Unfortunately the access to the whole database behind this feature doesn't seem to be (legally) free. There's this Python library https://github.com/m-wrzr/populartimes relying on Google data, but per https://github.com/m-wrzr/populartimes/issues/90 it's likely in violation of Google ToS, so I wouldn't call it a reliable service. In addition, the data comes from people who opted in Google Location History, so it is possibly biased depending on the place of interest. And I'm not sure if the data include street traffic, in addition to places' popular times.

Answer (score 1):

While not open, [BestTime.app](https://besttime.app/) is a "Foot traffic Data API".

<sup>-tip [Mickster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63223983/1429450) to "[Can I use the Google Places API to see a venue's busy hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60652129/1429450)"</sup>